# Starting KeystoneJS fail

Tags: node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

I try to set up my first project using KeystoneJS but when I try to use "node keystone" I receive the following error. Can anyone explain to me why is that?

```
Mongo Error:

[Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
/Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/mount.js:606
            throw new Error('KeystoneJS (' + keystone.get('name') + ') failed to start'
                  ^
Error: KeystoneJS (Doner) failed to start
    at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/mount.js:606:10)
    at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.error (/Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:389:8)
    at /Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:416:14
    at /Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:57:21
    at /Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:286:18
    at /Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:364:18
    at Server.close (/Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:192:38)
    at Db.close (/Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:360:21)
    at /Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:284:21
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:565:7)
    at emit (events.js:118:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/marius/Desktop/doner/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keystone could not connect to mongodb. Keystone doesn't manage MongoDB for you. So make sure MongoDB is running before "node keystone".

Answer (score 0):

You need to run mongod.

On mac:

```
sudo mongod
```

this will run mongodb and open a new terminal and after that run

```
node keystone
```

Same for windows if mongod is included in your path file other wise go to the directory where mongodb is located and run mongod.exe  it should be in

`program files/MongoDB/server/3.2/bin`